# How to combine Python context managers in a new function?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Let's say I have two [context managers](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html):

```
@contextmanager
def foo():
    [...]

@contextmanager
def bar():
    [...]
```

In Python 2.7 I can use both of them around a code block like this:

```
def do_something():
    with foo(), bar():
        [...]
```

But how can I combine both of them into a ***single* context manager** (for DRY/clarity):

```
@contextmanager
def foobar():
    [???]

def do_something():
    with foobar():
        [...]
```

I don't think I can simply call the other two context managers and expect that to work:

```
@contextmanager
def foobar():
    # Wrong(?)
    foo()
    bar()
```

Comment: Calling two different context managers isn't repeating yourself. Combining them seems unnecessary, unless you use both at the same time frequently.

Comment: Yes, this is a common use case when mocking during testing :)

Answer (score 1):

Since to be a context manager is essentially to have `__enter__` and `__exit__` that are called at certain points, combine those of `foo` and `bar` appropriately.

If you insist on using `contextlib.contextmanager` - again, replicate [the logic described in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html?highlight=contextmanager#contextlib.contextmanager):

> The function being decorated must return a generator-iterator when called. This iterator must yield exactly one value, which will be bound to the targets in the with statement’s as clause, if any.
>
> At the point where the generator yields, the block nested in the with statement is executed. The generator is then resumed after the block is exited. If an unhandled exception occurs in the block, it is reraised inside the generator at the point where the yield occurred. Thus, you can use a try...except...finally statement to trap the error (if any), or ensure that some cleanup takes place. If an exception is trapped merely in order to log it or to perform some action (rather than to suppress it entirely), the generator must reraise that exception. Otherwise the generator context manager will indicate to the with statement that the exception has been handled, and execution will resume with the statement immediately following the with statement.

```
def combined(*ff):
    bound_value=tuple(f.next() for f in ff)
    yield bound_value
    for f in ff:
        try: f.next()
        except StopIteration: pass
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this works, although I'm not sure if all corner cases are handled:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def bar():
    try:
        print 'enter bar'
        yield
    finally:
        print 'exit bar'

@contextmanager
def foo():
    try:
        print 'enter foo'
        yield
    finally:
        print 'exit foo'

@contextmanager
def foobar():
    try:
        with foo(), bar():
            print 'enter foobar'
            yield
    finally:
        print 'exit foobar'

with foobar():
    print 'hey'

enter foo
enter bar
enter foobar
hey
exit bar
exit foo
exit foobar
```

Answer (score -1):

You can combine multiple context managers into a single nested context manager with **nested** but It was [deprecated](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html) since version 2.7.
The **with** statement is doing the job of nested now. More info [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343).

Answer (score -1):

You could use `contextlib.nested` (wrapped in a lambda, to delay creating the separate context managers). However, this function has been deprecated in Python 2.7 precisely because you *can* have multiple context managers in a single `with` statement. Using two different context managers isn't repeating yourself, unless you use the two together frequently and/or exclusively.

```
something = lambda : contextlib.nested(foo(), bar())
with something():
    # ...
```

(Some may dislike using `lambda` here in place of a `def` statement:

```
def something():
    return contextlib.nested(foo(), bar())
```

)